# Bootstrap Tab Menu - navigate through several contents in the same tab using next previous buttons

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

My website has a vertical tab menu and I have to navigate through the tab using next/ previous buttons. I have done that part. But at the same time, I have to navigate through several tab contents in one particular tab using the same buttons.
Can someone please help me on this?

Thank you.

I used following function to navigate from one tab to another and I edited it as following to change the tab content without changing the active tab in the menu.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs " id="myTab" role="tablist">
            <li id="li1" class="nav-item active" ><a href="#a" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" class="nav-tab bg-transparent " style="text-align: center;" id="linkOne">
                </li>
            <li id="li2" class="nav-item" ><a href="#b" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" class="nav-tab bg-transparent " style="text-align: center;" id="linkTwo">
                </li>
            <li id="li3" class="nav-item" ><a href="#c" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" class="nav-tab bg-transparent " style="text-align: center;" id="linkThree">
                </li>
            <li id="li4" class="nav-item" ><a href="#d" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" class="nav-tab bg-transparent " style="text-align: center;" id="linkFour">
                </li>
            <li id="li5" class="nav-item" ><a href="#e" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" class="nav-tab bg-transparent " style="text-align: center;" id="linkFive">
                </li>               
        </ul>

<div class="tab-content" >
            <div class="tab-pane  active" id="a" >AAAA</div>
            <div class="tab-pane  active" id="b" >BBBB</div>
            <div class="tab-pane  active" id="c" >CCCC</div>
            <div class="tab-pane  active" id="d" >DDDD</div>
            <div class="tab-pane  active" id="d2" >D2D2D2D2</div>
           <div class="tab-pane  active" id="e" >EEEE</div>
</div>  


$(function () {
      $('.btnNext').click(function () {                                                    
      var currentAnchorID = $('.nav-tabs > .active').find('a').attr("id");                                                    
       if (currentAnchorID == 'linkFour')
       {
                  var currentTabContentID = $('.nav-tabs > .active').find('a').attr("href").replace("#", "");
                      if (currentTabContentID == 'd')
                      {
                           $("d").tab('hide');
                           $("d2").tab('show');                                                            
                      }
                      else
                      {
                            $('.nav-tabs > .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
                      }                                                        
        }           
       else
        {
                   $('.nav-tabs > .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
         }                                                    
      });

      $('.btnPrevious').click(function () {
       $('.nav-tabs > .active').prev('li').find('a').trigger('click');

       });
     });
```

Comment: more  code and  illustrations will help your question to get answer faster.

Comment: @Crystal I added some more code . Can you please check?

Comment: I can, so you want to call your content to show it, is that right? If you put more of your code I will be able to help. The more you provide the more it's easier for me. I can make a pretend nav and content but I want to make sure I understand you right. Do you want a different way or you want your way?

Comment: I included the code edited by me. But it is not working. Please help.